# standard \cup vs musixtex's \cup

Tags: errors, symbols

I'm using the `musixtex` package and it contains a `\cup` command (command for a dotted note). Unfortunately, I need the usual `\cup` command  (command for the union of sets).

Now, LaTeX doesn't recognize the 'normal' `\cup` command and gives me an error.

What could I do to solve the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Answer (score 10):

The definition of of `\cup` can be stored in other macros, see the example.
In this case the `\cup` of `musixtex` is probably not used in math mode, thus a "switcher" macro `\cup` can be defined that uses the mathematical `\cup` in math mode and the `\cup` of `musixtex` otherwise:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\mathcup\cup
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\musixcup\cup

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cup}{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathcup
  \else
    \expandafter\musixcup
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  Musical note: \musixcup 0 \qquad \cup 0\\
  Math: $A \mathcup B = A \cup B$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]